# Hide and remove all space of nested UIView swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, constraints

I am trying to hide and remove the space of the `MainUIView`.I tried to make the `MainUIView` `heightConstarint` to `0` . But it is not hiding the views inside them.

I want to hide all the view and labels inside the `MainUIView`.
hope you understand my problem.Thank you in advance

Here is my code

```
@IBOutlet weak var heightConstarint:NSLayoutConstraint!
//@IBOutlet weak var viewhide: UIView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    heightConstarint.constant = 0
    //self.viewhide.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

[image]

Comment: is there any height constraint provided to the view in which View1 and view2 are added

Comment: No i didnt add any  height constraint  for View1 view2 and label.But it is not remove all space

Comment: Does the console show any `conflicting constraints` warning?

Comment: No i didnt get any warning to console

Comment: You can set `MainUIView.layer.masksToBounds = true`, this will tell the `MainUIView` that it needs to clip all inserted views to it's frame.

Answer (score 1):

Updating Constraints will Never work in

**override func viewDidLoad(){}**

If you want to change constraints programmatically then you must put your code in

**override fun viewWillLayoutSubviews(){}**

So your code will look like

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {

     clipToBounds = true
     heightConstarint.constant = 0
     //self.viewhide.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
     self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

}
```

Comment: don't forgot to select ClipToBounds = true for superview

Comment: Thanks a lot Tandel. making ClipToBounds = true works.please update the answer.Hope it will help some one

Answer (score 0):

I don't know updating constraints will work or not in `viewDidLoad`. But there are another constraints for `MainUIView`.

[image]

I think you should remove top or bottom space.

Comment: Thank you .Yes i  remove top or bottom space and make view ClipToBounds = true.It works

Comment: Works in viewDidLoad?